# GLM model explanation

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

Can anyone please tell me what kind of model is being run with the following R call:

```
glm.fit(covar,pred,family = binomial())
```

I know what `glm.fit` does, but what is the specific name of the model when someone supplies `binomial()` as the family parameter and can you give me some references to it?

Answer (score 3):

It's saying the response is binomial; this specifies the variance function and the default link function in particular, the model is that

$\text{E}(Y_i) = n_i \pi_i \,$, and

$\text{Var}(Y_i) = n_i \pi_i (1-\pi_i)$

and where the default link function is $\text{logit}(\pi_i) = X_i \beta$

It's possible to change to one of a couple of other link functions, and to introduce a non-unit dispersion parameter into the variance function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binomial_data

Comment: Is this the "simple" logit model?

Comment: The information in my answer applies to multiple predictors. $X_i$ is a row-vector (the $\text{i}^{\text{th}}$ row of the $X$-matrix) and $\beta$ is a vector of coefficients.

Comment: What i mean is whether or not any code that implements logit should return the *same* values as if i were doing this in R with the same dataset?

I'm having trouble reproducing this with some libraries in Java and want to make sure that i'm using the right libraries.

Comment: I am sorry, it seems I don't follow you at all. Are you trying to code GLM yourself?

Comment: updated my comment above.

Comment: On the information provided I have no way of answering the question. I don't know what the libraries are doing at all. When you say 'logit' are you referring to `logit(p) = ln(p/(1-p))`? If not, what are you talking about and what are these libraries doing? You seem to be assuming a level of mindreading that I don't possess. Perhaps you should generate a new question, as long as it's on topic.